# $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\int_0^x e^{t^2} dt\right)^{\frac 1 {x^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

> Prove that $$e=\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(\int_0^x e^{t^2} \mathrm{d}t\right)^{\frac {1}{x^2}}.$$

I tried to take the logarithm of this expression and use the integral mean value theorem - for all $x>0$ there exists a point $c\in (0,x)$ such that $e^{c^2} =\frac 1 x \int_0^x e^{t^2} \mathrm{d}t$, so by taking logarithm we have
$$\ln \left( \left( \int_0^x e^{t^2}  \mathrm{d} t \right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)=\frac{1}{x^2} \ln (x\cdot e^{c^2})=\frac{c^2}{x^2}\ln x.$$
If we establish a better bound on $c$ this might be useful; but I couldn't find a continuation.

Comment: [See here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1818221p12137546).

Comment: @Robert FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24e%3D%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D(%5Cint_0%5Ex%20e%5E%7Bt%5E2%7Ddt)%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E2%7D%7D%24&p=1), the top result is the AoPS thread [Integration limit](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1818221p12137546), that Sarvesh's comment above also references.

Comment: $$\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt=x\int_0^1e^{x^2t^2}dt\overset{t\to1-t}{=}xe^{x^2}\int_0^1e^{x^2(t^2-2t)}dt$$
As at $t\in[0;1]\,\,t^2-2t\leqslant t-2t=-t$
$$\frac{1-e^{-2x^2}}{2x^2}=\int_0^1e^{-2x^2t}dt\leqslant\int_0^1e^{x^2(t^2-2t)}dt\leqslant \int_0^1e^{-x^2t}dt=\frac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x^2}$$
The limit follows.

Comment: @Robert, look at my answer. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proof without using L'Hospital's rule.

Since $\;e^{2t}\geqslant2t+1>2t-2\;\;$ for any $\,t\in(-\infty,+\infty)\;,$

it follows that

$(2t-2)e^{t^2-2t}<e^{t^2}\quad$ for any $\,t\in(-\infty,+\infty)\;\;,$

$\displaystyle\int_0^x(2t-2)e^{t^2-2t}\,\mathrm dt<\int_0^x e^{t^2}\mathrm dt\quad$ for any $\,x\in(0,+\infty)\;\;,$

$\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{t^2-2t}\,\mathrm d\!\left(t^2-2t\right)<\int_0^x e^{t^2}\mathrm dt\quad$ for any $\,x\in(0,+\infty)\;\;,$

$\displaystyle e^{x^2-2x}-1=\left[e^{t^2-2t}\right]_0^x<\int_0^x e^{t^2}\mathrm dt\quad$ for any $\,x\in(0,+\infty)\;.$

On the other hand , for any $\,x\in[3,+\infty)\,,$

$\displaystyle e^{x^2-2x-1}<2e^{x^2-2x-1}-1=\dfrac2ee^{x^2-2x}-1<e^{x^2-2x}-1\;.$

Consequently ,

$\displaystyle e^{x^2-2x-1}<\!\int_0^x\!e^{t^2}\mathrm dt<xe^{x^2}\!\!<e^xe^{x^2}\!\!=e^{x^2+x}\quad\forall\,x\!\in[3,+\infty)\;,$

$\displaystyle\left(e^{x^2-2x-1}\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}\!\!<\left(\!\int_0^x\!e^{t^2}\mathrm dt\!\right)^{\!\frac1{x^2}}\!\!<\left(e^{x^2+x}\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}\quad\forall\,x\!\in[3,+\infty)\;,$

$\displaystyle e^{1-\frac2x-\frac1{x^2}}<\left(\int_0^x\!e^{t^2}\mathrm dt\right)^{\!\frac1{x^2}}\!<e^{1+\frac1x}\quad\forall\,x\!\in[3,+\infty)\;.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

Since $\,\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}e^{1-\frac2x-\frac1{x^2}}=\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}e^{1+\frac1x}=e\;,\;$ from $\,(*)\,$ by applying the Squeeze Theorem, it follows that

$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} \left(\int_0^x\!e^{t^2}\mathrm dt\right)^{\!\frac1{x^2}}=e\;.$

Answer (score 2):

An integration by parts yields:
$$
\int_{1}^{x} \mathrm{e}^{t^2}\ \mathrm{d}t
=
\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{2t}\,2t\,\mathrm{e}^{t^2}\ \mathrm{d}t
=
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x^2}}{2x}-\frac{\mathrm{e}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{t^2}}{t^2}\ \mathrm{d}t.
$$
Since $\frac{\mathrm{e}^{t^2}}{t^2}=\mathrm{o}(\mathrm{e}^{t^2})$ as $t$ tends to  $+\infty$ and since $t\mapsto \mathrm{e}^{t^2}$ is positive and not integrable over  $[1,{+\infty}[$, we have:
$$
\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{t^2}}{t^2}\ \mathrm{d}t=\mathrm{o}\left(\int_{1}^{x} \mathrm{e}^{t^2}\ \mathrm{d}t\right).
$$
This implies that:
$$
\int_{1}^{x} \mathrm{e}^{t^2}\ \mathrm{d}t\underset{x\to{+\infty}}{\sim} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{x^2}}{2x}
\qquad \text{and then}\qquad 
\int_{0}^{x} \mathrm{e}^{t^2}\ \mathrm{d}t\underset{x\to{+\infty}}{\sim} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{x^2}}{2x}.
$$
Consequently, we deduce that:
$$
\ln\left(\int_{0}^{x} \mathrm{e}^{t^2}\ \mathrm{d}t\right)\underset{x\to{+\infty}}{\sim} x^2
$$
and then:
$$
\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\left(\int_{0}^{x} \mathrm{e}^{t^2}\ \mathrm{d}t\right)\underset{x\to{+\infty}}{\sim} 1.
$$

Finally, by the continuity of the exponential function, we obtain:

$$
\lim_{x\to{+\infty}} \left(\int_{0}^{x} \mathrm{e}^{t^2}\ \mathrm{d}t\right)^{1/x^2}=\mathrm{e}
$$